# Json to Array vs Array to Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, dictionary

changed around stuff relating to comments:
so now I have on ViewDidLoad:

```
 let itemsListJson:String = "jsons/items"

    guard let urlItems = Bundle.main.url(forResource: itemsListJson, withExtension: "json") else { return }

    do{
        let dataItems = try Data(contentsOf: urlItems)
        let jsonItems = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: dataItems, options: .mutableContainers)

        guard let arrayItems = jsonItems as? [Any] else {return}

        dump(jsonItems)

        UserDefaults.standard.set(arrayItems, forKey: "items")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

    }
    catch{
        print(error)
    }
```

that prints out my object

▿ 38 elements #0
  ▿ 9 key/value pairs #1
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - key: armor #2
        - super: NSString
          - super: NSObject
      - value: 3 #3
        - super: NSString
          - super: NSObject
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - key: min_damage #4
        - super: NSMutableString
          - super: NSString
            - super: NSObject
      - value: 0 #5
        - super: NSString
          - super: NSObject
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - key: id #6
        - super: NSString
          - super: NSObject
      - value: 1 #7
        - super: NSString
          - super: NSObject
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - key: speed #8

When I try using:

```
guard let arrayItems = jsonItems as? [String: Any] else {return}
```

I get no results.

How do I save my data as a dictionary. I just can't figure this out and examples out there are too old to be of any use. Please help

Comment: Why don't you get the URL instead of contructing your url from the path? `guard let urlItems = Bundle.main.url(forResource: items_list_json, withExtension: "json") else {
        print("fail")
        return

    }` Note that it is Swift naming convention to use `camelCase` not `snake_case`

Comment: You can't cast an array to an unrelated type (dictionary). If you need a dictionary you will need to change your property list file adding a dictionary as it root object.

Comment: And last but not least, don't use `value(forKey:)`. UserDefaults has an specific method for loading dictionary values called `dictionary(forKey:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1408563-dictionary there is also a specific one for arrays called `array(forKey:)` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414792-array

Comment: @LeoDabus could you show a small example. I know how to turn a json coming from a url to a Dictionary. Just can't figure out how to do it when json is embedded within the project. I tried constructing url from path and I get a result but am unsure how to use that

Answer (score 0):

The following two lines of code show your problem:

```
guard let array_items = json_items as? [Any] else {return}

let zitems:Dictionary = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "items") as? [String:Any])!
```

In the first, you declare json_items as `[Any]`, and write it to the key "items". In the second, you read "items" and now expect it to be `[String:Any]`.

Comment: I did try using:  guard let array_items = json_items as? [String:Any] else {return}  but it returned empty

Comment: Since your `dump` is producing a valid array, you should be loading it back in as an array, not a dictionary. Each element of the array is probably a dictionary.

Comment: Yep. I figured it out. The json is an array of dictionaries